# Change font type of printer in CUPS

Tags: java, printing, fonts, cups, cups4j

I am simply looking for a way to change the font type of a printer in CUPS.

I have tried updating fonts, changing PPD's, changing font directories, and updating charset files.

The only partial solution I found was to change the charset file to contain the font type I wanted.

However, this changes the font type throughout CUPS and on all printers.

Does anyone know how to change one printer to print with a certain font and another printer to print with a different font?

NOTE: I am using CUPS on a RHEL box and cups4j to spawn the job through java.

Thanks

Comment: Normally you use the postscript command to change the font.

Comment: How is this a Java question?  In fact, how is this even a programming question?

Comment: We are using cups4j which is a java library to interface with CUPS on a RHEL server. The Cups4j api allows the developer to utilize certain options to specify printer defaults (Page Orientation, Page Size, etc.). I was hoping someone had used cups4j before and had implemented font type changes through the api. This, as far as I understand, qualifies it as not only a programming question but in fact a java question as well. Also away with you if you dont have any useful input you crazy fool.

Comment: Thanks Stark. Could you expand on this? What postscript commands do you mean? And this seems possible through CUPS itself if I am using LPR to send a print command, but how could I incorporate it into cups4j or configuration on the CUPS defined printers themselves?